# solr data import handler takes too long time

Tags: solr, dih

When I try to import all the data from database using full-import command, the sql query is three joint tables with each 1M records. It's taking too much time for the first request made to datasource. I haven't got the complete result until now.

from command=status,

Total requests make to datasource is always "1"

What's the process workflow of data import handler, why the first request to datasource is so time-consuming? How to improve full-import performance?

Thanks.

Comment: I got the solution by adding fetch size parameter. Thanks everyone